# What is Stack Overflow's criteria for judging a title potentially subjective?

Tags: support

I very often get this warning box when posting a question on S.O.:

[image: a]

More often than not, the question turns out not to be closed as subjective. Indeed, most of the questions, such as this, is objective in the sense it has an unambiguous answer. What criterion is used here?

Comment: It might be catching on the "you" in "how do you". Maybe rewrite the title in a "why does x when y"?

Comment: How do you suggest writing that particular title?

Comment: I would need more context from the post. A person commented (and deleted) saying that it might be too broad. Try including some crucial information and things you have tried in the title.

Comment: Heuristic, but still pretty good. The specific detaills are not available for public scrutiny to slightly hamper gaming it.

Comment: It's unlikely that the criteria is going to be public, as that would allow easy gaming to bypass it. Just trust that the criteria is most likely valid for the majority of posts where the warning is displayed; yours may be an exception, but you could consider rephrasing it to improve your chances of it not being correct.

Comment: "How to write rewrite rules for typeclass methods?" doesn't trigger warning. It is as if system feels the difference between "how do you" and "how to" (not that I' surprised, heuristics is fairly straightforward)

Comment: "How do you do X?" does not contain any more information than "X".  The title need not end with a question mark: "Split a string into an array of characters" is a better title than "How do you split a string into an array of characters?" Removing the filler is likely to make you realize that the title (now simply "Rewrite rules for typeclass method") is not as specific as it could be.

Answer (score 6):

It's extremely simple; it just looks for a few keywords. On English-speaking sites, they are "best", "worst", "hardest", "you", "your", "favo(u)rite", "good for", "bad for".

This very simple heuristic does a pretty good job at catching many subjective questions early, but of course not every question with one of those words in the title will actually be subjective. "How do you implement a generic factory provider interface manager without running into type erasure issues?" *isn't* subjective. "How do you cope with your hate for Java in your day job?" *is* subjective.

So yes, you'll have false positives, but the little popup is just a warning, it doesn't block you from posting. It's just meant to make the user think for a moment whether they're really creating a good question. If you're certain that you are, move along and ignore the popup.

Which is also why it's not an issue (as some comments on your question suggested) to make the criteria public, and in fact they have [never been a secret](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/20014/115866).

Comment: Its a good practice, but I can imagine that the way it is phrased now will trigger rebellion and anger more than it does reason.

Comment: @Gimby This was added over six years ago (on April 18, 2009, to be precise) with the exact phrasing that's still used today. I'm sure the rebellion would have happened by now :)

Comment: okay you got me :) *feelings of rebellion* is more what I was going for ;)

Comment: Grab yer pitchforks and torches guys, theys is scannin ar' question titles! [@Gimby](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302979/what-is-stack-overflows-criteria-for-judging-a-title-potentially-subjective#comment236602_303005)